How would you address slavery in the Tanakh?
I was reading my Tanakh and I obviously came across verses that endorse or regulate slavery (Exodus 21:2-6, Leviticus 25:44-46, Deuteronomy 15:12-15) how would you address slavery in the Tanakh and does G-d in this verses condone slavery?
